# function being called, not executing

Tags: jquery, url-parameters

Given some URL parameter being passed: 
/login.jsp?requestinfo=username

Almost everything seems to be working fine but when I call the showRequestInfo function it does not execute. It is not receiving the parameter being passed to it. Why this may be failing?

JS:

```
function LoginView(model, options) {
this.LoginModel = model;
this.bindEvents();
this.GetURLParameter();
}

//check for parameters being passed
//if params. are present show requested screen
LoginView.prototype.GetURLParameter = function (sParam) {
var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1);
var sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&');
for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
    var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
    if (sParameterName[0] == sParam) {
        return sParameterName[1]; 
    }
}
   this.showRequestInfo(UrlParameter);
};

LoginView.prototype.showRequestInfo = function (sParam) {

var UrlParameter = GetURLParameter('requestinfo');
if (UrlParameter == 'username') {

    var getMyUsername = $('#getmyusername');

    if (getMyUsername.hasClass('notvisible')) {
        $('#logincontainer').animate({'left':'-280px'}, 'fast');
        $('#logincontainer').removeClass('visible');
        $('#logincontainer').addClass('notvisible');                
        getMyUsername.removeClass('notvisible');
        getMyUsername.animate({'left':'35px'}, 'slow').addClass('visible');             
    }
}

else if (UrlParameter == 'password') {

    var getMyPassword = $('#getmypassword');

    if (getMyPassword.hasClass('notvisible')) {
        $('#logincontainer').animate({'left':'-280px'}, 'fast');
        $('#logincontainer').removeClass('visible'); 
        $('#logincontainer').addClass('notvisible');               
        getMyPassword.removeClass('notvisible');
        getMyPassword.animate({'left':'35px'}, 'slow').addClass('visible');             
    }
} 

};
```

How come my showRequestInfo function is not getting executed?

Comment: "When I call the showRequestInfo function it does not execute" seems like an anti-tautology that implies a huge bug in the JavaScript language. Put simply: What, specifically, are you doing in attempt to call the function?

Comment: hello Katana,
if  url parameter is ?requestinfo=username, then show a given form on the page that will allow user to request their username. Basically this is one of those "forgot username" or "forgot password" when a user has forgotten their credentials to login to a site.